# My website does not show images when viewed in Firefox, but works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm aware that this is nothing new and will happen, but I've just run out of ideas of what to correct. I tried validating my website code, fixed encoding, but to no avail.

Here it is: [www.arturstols.com](http://www.arturstols.com) (you click the logo)

It uses jQuery to slide images inside the central container, which doesn't show. The intro graphic does though.

Comment: it says cant load url :S It thinks the src is http://www.arturstols.com/images%5Crukitis.jpg

Comment: It does not work in Google chrome to at connection speed 512 Kb/s It seems to be loading files problem.

Comment: -1 for not showing relevant code.  Question is useless to future readers with only your URL, which will get fixed or changed.

Comment: @Sparky I think that answers may accumulate with the question for the future reader.

Comment: @sємsєм, that's not the point.  As per much discussion by SO's top users at SO Meta site, questions should be "self-contained" and not simply rely on a link to external code.  Also voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `images\pic.png` put `images/pic.png` .

Comment: Now I'm just embarrassed. Thank you very much. I don't get why it worked in Chrome in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You are using the incorrect slash for the image urls...

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img alt="" src="images\title_903x600.jpg" style="margin: 5px 0px;">
    <img alt="" src="images\rukitis.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\danny.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\ernests.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\toms.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\forest.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\fight.jpg">                                 
    <img alt="" src="images\light.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\mirror.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images\scene.jpg">
</div>
```

should be...

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img alt="" src="images/title_903x600.jpg" style="margin: 5px 0px;">
    <img alt="" src="images/rukitis.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/danny.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/ernests.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/toms.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/forest.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/fight.jpg">                                 
    <img alt="" src="images/light.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/mirror.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="images/scene.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify image src paths using a forward slash. 
For eg.

```
<img alt="" src="images/title_903x600.jpg">
```

instead of

```
<img alt="" src="images\title_903x600.jpg">
```

as you have currently specified.

This solves the issue for firefox. Chrome is extra smart :)

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, i like your photography but it seemed to load slowly, perhaps look into a jquery pre load function.

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
this.each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
});
```

}

// Usage:

$(['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg']).preload();