# <img> tag not working on Mozilla Firefox and IE ... changing the slash doesn't work for me

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, firefox

I have used `img` tag to display images in my HTML page. The code works fine with `Google chrome`, but doesn't work on `firefox` or `IE` . Just an empty box appears.

What could be the possible reasons for this? I think the code is fine. Could there be any browser problems or something?

here's the code `<img src="C:\Users\g500\Documents\AlbumArtSmall.jpg" />`

Comment: Could we see your code please?

Comment: Code will explain your problem.

Comment: As the others said, we can't help you without seeing your code. However (and this is a wild guess) I believe your img path is wrong - check your trailing slash - `<img src="foo\bar.png" />` should be `<img src="foo/bar.png" />`

Comment: here's the code - <img src="C:\Users\g500\Documents\AlbumArtSmall.jpg" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [My website does not show images when viewed in Firefox, but works perfectly in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995439/my-website-does-not-show-images-when-viewed-in-firefox-but-works-perfectly-in-c)

Comment: changing the slash doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Add file:/// at the beginning of the path.